# SQL: How do I refer to the result of a previous query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT fName from employees where ssn=123456789;
```

Suppose I want to follow the previous query with another one:

```
SELECT fName from records WHERE ssn=123456789;
SELECT lName from records WHERE fName=(the result of the previous query)
```

What do I put in for `(the result of the previous query)` to make this return the last names from records where the fName matches the presumably unique record where ssn=123456789?

I know that this is an unrealistic example, but what I'm asking is, "How do I refer to the result of my previous query?"

BTW, if it makes any difference, I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.  Thanks!

Comment: What's your actual use for this? Do you actually **need** to have it split in two queries?

Comment: This is not an example of something I'm actually doing.  I'm simply using these statements to pose the question: "When I'm writing a query, how do I refer to the result of the previous query?"

I know I've seen this somewhere before, but try as I might, I can't seem to find it again...

Comment: join,subquery,variable,CTE,cross apply, temp table in roughly that order!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can save the result of the first query into a variable and use that variable in the second query.

```
DECLARE @firstName VARCHAR(255)
SELECT @firstName = fName from employees where ssn=123456789

SELECT lName from records WHERE fName=@firstName
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the first `SELECT` returns more than one row.

Comment: If the SELECT returns more than one row then the variable type can be set to TABLE

Answer (score 10):

There are three obvious ways of doing this. You can use SQL variables, temp tables (or table variables, they are roughly equivalent) or you can use a subquery.

**SQL Variables**

Here you store your desired value in a variable (the @fname piece of code below) and then you can use this later. With this approach you want to be careful that your SSN really is the unique identifer.

```
Declare @fname Varchar(50)

Select @fname = fname 
from employees 
Where ssn = 123456789

Select lName from records
where fname = @fname
```

**Temp Table**

With a temp table you create a table of the records that you want. This can then be used later on, and to get the records you want you then use the temp table within a sub query.

You can either declare the temp table as a separate `create table` statement, or declare it as part of your select as I do below.

```
Select fname into #temptable
From employees
Where ssn = 123456789

Select lName from records
where fname in 
(
    Select fname 
    from #temptable
)
```

**Sub Query**

This is actually quite similar to the temp table approach, but you inline the temp table part, so you can't refer to it again later.

```
Select @fname = fname 
from employees 
Where ssn = 123456789

Select lName from records
where fname in 
(
   Select fname 
   from employees 
   Where ssn = 123456789 
)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT lName from records WHERE fName =(SELECT fName from employees where ssn=123456789)
```

OR

```
 SELECT lName from records r
 INNER JOIN employees e ON (e.fName = r.fName)
 WHERE e.ssn = 123456789
```

OR you can also use CTE.